# Is there a requirement for Electrical Design Engineers to show all their design computations/analysis used on electrical plan?

Tags: power-supply, design

There was a Terms of Reference requiring to provide 100% back-up power on all residential units of a building.

However, I noticed that the designer-in-charge did not include provisional loads on their total computation. I am concerned that it may result in insufficient supply later on, or that the design is not 100% ready, since they already excluded loads before arriving on the total computed load, and before the application of demand factor, etc.

Comment: You have asked the question on an international site but have given no location information in the question or in your user profile and the answer will be location specific. Can you fix this? Hit the [edit] link below your question ...

Answer (score 1):

In the USA Document Control Procedures determine if and what computational analysis is required to go with a buildings electrical diagrams. Unless the owner specifies and pays for a backup system, there is none.

However, since hurricane Katrina cell phone towers are required to have at least 3 days or more of backup power. Hospitals have backup power as a standard installation. As a home owner or apartment owner you are on your own.

Many people here in Florida buy and install their own backup generators mostly for the refrigerator. A backup UPS for computers and TV is a must. During the summer if the power is out more than two days we have to travel to someplace with AC.

Answer (score 0):

Normally there are voluntary guidelines recommended for Multi-Unit-Residential-Buildings (MURBs).  We do not know your circumstances.  I extracted the [following](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiTmLqr2L_YAhWs4IMKHRDzAPkQFggvMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.toronto.ca%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2017%2F11%2F91ca-Minimum-Backup-Power-Guideline-for-MURBs-October-2016.pdf&usg=AOvVaw1fmBdX8k3iTNTc_z1QDzRE) from recent guidelines written for Toronto, Canada.

> During sustained area-wide power outages, emergency power is not designed to keep residents in their buildings with any degree of comfort, even if there is no particular problem with the building. However, backup power is provided to meet non-life safety requirements that are considered essential for occupant
>   well-being (e.g. water supply, heating, elevators), such that occupants can remain in their building safely and with a degree of comfort for at least 72 hours.